# li nth child with multiply in css

Tags: html, css

I have a calendar layout, it has rows and column , each row for sure will have 7 column since in a week there will be 7 days. How can I use css to target the last item of each row?

I'm stuck at this

```
li:nth-child(7)
li:nth-child(14)
```

etc

is there any better way to do this like using math in css?

Comment: This should work:    li:nth-child(7n) {
        // your styles
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
li:nth-child(7n+0) {
    background: red;
}
```

Example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        li:nth-child(7n+0) {
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <li>The 1 li element.</li>
    <li>The 2 li element.</li>
    <li>The 3 li element.</li>
    <li>The 4 li element.</li>
    <li>The 5 li element.</li>
    <li>The 6 li element.</li>
    <li>The 7 li element.</li>
    <li>The 8 li element.</li>
    <li>The 9 li element.</li>

    <li>The 10 li element.</li>
    <li>The 11 li element.</li>
    <li>The 12 li element.</li>
    <li>The 13 li element.</li>
    <li>The 14 li element.</li>
    <li>The 15 li element.</li>
    <li>The 16 li element.</li>
    <li>The 17 li element.</li>
    <li>The 18 li element.</li>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `li:nth-child(7n)` .

> This way it will only target the **7th element** of li everytime.

```css
*{margin:0pc; padding:0px; box-sizing:border-box;}
li{ width:14.287%; display:inline-block;}
li:nth-child(7n){ color:red;}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li><li>Test</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: The only issue though, is that some weeks wont have 7 items unless he is wrapping into the following month.

Comment: @Cam so you want the last li of every row to be targeted?

Comment: Well, the OP wrote: _How can I use css to target the last item of each row?_ ... so you missed the actual question?

Comment: @LGSon yes you are right. But the the OP accepted a similar answer afterwards , thats why I inquired what is the actuall requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul li:nth-child(7n+0){ color: red }
```

```html
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to select every seventh list item:

`li:nth-child(7n)`

Also, you can test `nth-child` selectors at http://nth-test.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to select every seventh list item:

```
:nth-child(7n)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        ul :nth-child(7n) {
            background: blue;
            color: white
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
   <ul>
    <li>li-1</li>
    <li>li-2</li>
    <li>li-3</li>
    <li>li-4</li>
    <li>li-5</li>
    <li>li-6</li>
    <li>li-7</li>
    <li>li-8</li>
    <li>li-9</li>
    <li>li-10</li>
    <li>li-11</li>
    <li>li-12</li>
    <li>li-13</li>
    <li>li-14</li>
    <li>li-15</li>
    <li>li-16</li>
    <li>li-17</li>
    <li>li-18</li>
    <li>li-19</li>
    <li>li-20</li>
    <li>li-21</li>
    <li>li-22</li>
   <li>li-23</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```